# wxPython Draw A Triangle

Tags: python, wxpython, drawing

I understand that this is a very simple question, but how do you draw a triangle using `wxpython`?  A simple example would be much appreciated.

I tried using `dc.DrawPolygon(self, points, xoffset, yoffset, fillStyle)`, but I didn't know what to pass in for `fillstyle`.  All my efforts resulted in odd error messages.

Sorry for such a novice question!

Comment: Have you looked at [the docs](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html#DrawPolygon)?

Comment: In the future, don't just vaguely describe your code and say "odd error messages", show your relevant code (ideally a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the actual exception and traceback that it created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html#DrawPolygon) say:

> The last argument specifies the fill rule: `wx.ODDEVEN_RULE` (the default) or `wx.WINDING_RULE`.

So, those are the only two values you can pass for `fillstyle`. If you pass anything else, you'll probably get an exception.

But notice that it has a perfectly good default. If you're drawing complicated concave polygons sometimes you need the other rule. (If that comes up, you will have to learn what the two rules mean; I don't think the `wx` docs cover it, but Wikipedia might be a good place to start.) But most of the time, you can just leave it off and use the default:

```
my_dc.DrawPolygon(my_points, my_xoffset, my_yoffset)
```